# Disable touchpad when using mouse in Win 10 on HP EliteBook 8440p

Tags: laptop, windows-10, mouse, touchpad

Is there a way of doing this on my laptop?  I once found a solution on an old Toshiba for Win7 (something I had to download) but that one died and I got a Dell (also Win7) where that option was available, no need to download anything.  Now I have this HP (still have the Dell as well) and I can only find a setting to make the touchpad less responsive, not to disable it when I am using the mouse.  I don't want to completely uninstall it, because I may need it at times when a mouse is not available.  TBH, I don't much like the idea of making it less responsive either, because when I do need to use it, I may forget that I have set it and may just be sitting there swearing at it, or, someone else may want to use it...
ATM there is a Synaptics TouchPad V7.2 and a Synaptics TouchStyk V2.0 installed.  A found another post (about a different brand computer) where there was a link to a new Synaptics download (the suggestion being to uninstall the present driver and install the new one) but the link pointed at a Windows 7 driver, so wasn't sure if I should install that

Comment: You should only install Windows 10 compatible drivers for your Synaptics touchpad if you want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

This may help if you want to have "Disable internal pointing device when external USB pointing device is attached" option in the synaptics control panel without having to install a different touchpad driver:

> Open regedit and go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTPEnh,
>   right click and select New > DWORD (32-bit) Value and name it
>   "DisableIntPDFeature". Modify its value to 33 in hexadecimal, or 51 in
>   decimal.

Additionally, you may need to make similar modification(s) under HKEY_CURRENT_USER, but the above modification was sufficient for me.

Answer (score 0):

New touchpads have a functionality built in that can enable/disable them.
Some that I've used even have a light on/off to show the lock status they have atm.

Just hold your finger in the left upper corner of your touchupad to see if you have it.

If using Synaptics - their drivers offer configure-ability on the matter.

If both the first post and mine don't help you you might want to look into making a simple script via command line to detect if your mouse is connected and to enable/disable the device.

P.S. If you don't have a driver - get one. If its a branded laptop better get it off the brand's website, not the manufacturer one.

Comment: had to install drivers for a HP Probook touchpad from the hp.com website, then I could enable/disable touchpad with the button in its corner.

Comment: Its typical for most branded laptops.

Answer (score 0):

If you've driver properly installed, then in the task bar tray (where time displays in windows) there must be a small icon indicating synaptics touchpad our touch stick (if you've not hidden some of the icons, in which case you may have to click a small up pointing arrow). Double Click that icon (if you don't find it somewhere, locate the same in control panel thru mouse options).

There in the last tab of that dialogue, the last tab is 'Device Settings'. There you select the device to be disabled and then click 'Disable' just below that. Refer the SS attached.